# Some help please... IE + JQuery load() not displaying results

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, load

I am working with another developers code... But I do not think there is an issue there... The page should submit a search form which is intercepted by getResults() serialized and then injects the results into the desired empty div.

## Potential Issue: IE cache with .load() as chrome and FFox work

So the problem is that Jquery's load() fails to display result in IE unless I frantically refresh the page.  This leads me to believe that like many i am having a cache issue here.  Yet many hours of searching and modifying the load() has resulted in the same issue.

## What have I tried so far:

changing load() to get().
adding timestamp.
rebuilding with ajax request (had some joy locally but when put live this did not work either)
Set ajax cache to false. 
removed e.preventDefault() this worked but forced the page to refresh (not acceptable unfortunately)
checked HTML validity and ensured (text/javascript) throughout.
I have included jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js for compatibility. < IE9
encodeURIComponent()

## Where I am:

my $data is full of \r\n\t (newlines I guess) and I dont see this when debugging in Chrome or FF does anyone know how this happend?

## GetResults()

```
    function getResults(){

    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $('#vrSearchForm').submit(function(e) {

                        var ok = false;

            var target = document.getElementById('spin');

            var spin = new     Spinner({color:'rgb(255,156,33)',radius:50,lines:8,width:10,shadow:true}).spin(target);

            var pos = $('.returned-properties').position();

            var form = $(this);

            serializedData = form.serialize();

            $('.returned-properties').empty();

            $('#results').remove();

            $('#more-results').css("display","inline");

            $('.returned-properties').load('index.php #results',serializedData, function(data) {

                $('body').animate({

                    scrollTop: pos.top - 100

                },800);

                spin.stop();

                                var working = data;

                                if (status != "error") {
                                if (($.browser.msie))
                                    response.replace(/\r\n/g, "");
                                }

                                if (typeof history.pushState != 'undefined') { 
                                    ok = true;
                                    history.pushState(serializedData,"", "index.php?" + serializedData);
                                }else{
                                    location.hash = "index.php?" + serializedData;
                                }
            });
                    e.preventDefault();

                    return false;
    });

});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short... One additional div tag.  Was not spotted by the W3 validation tools and the real closing div tag was just off screen so not immediately obvious at all, in addition to this everything worked in Chrome and FireFox.  No errors, no feedback at all from IE just zero output.